# Why does feof return a different result when it is used with fseek and fread?

Tags: php, fread, fseek, feof

While debugging a function I am implementing, I noticed a different return result from `feof` when it is used with `fseek` or `fread`, would you explain to me why `feof` is unable to test the end of file when `fseek` get involved?

```
$file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
// Do some operations on the file then seek to end of it
fseek($file, 0, SEEK_END);
echo ftell($file) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(feof($file));
echo '##############################################################' . PHP_EOL;

rewind($file);
while(!feof($file))
{
    fread($file, 500);
}

echo ftell($file) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(feof($file));
fclose($file);
```

Output:

```
3505
bool(false)
##############################################################
3505
bool(true)
```

Comment: `feof()` returns `true` if the *last* read failed because it was at EOF. It doesn't tell you if you're at EOF before you read.

Comment: Have a read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php#67261

Comment: @Barmar Can you suggest any other methods to test the end of file?

Comment: Read the linked question. `fread()` and other input functions return `FALSE` when you call them at EOF.

Comment: @Barmar It seems the `FILE` structure has a flag set when read reach the end of file, and `feof` is the checker for that.

Comment: @HAßdøµ Correct, but it's not set until *after* you try to read something at EOF.

Comment: The underlying OS file-reading API doesn't provide any way to tell when you're at EOF without trying to read something first.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, and it is set by `read`.

Comment: But you're checking for EOF *before* you read. Read the linked question to see the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar I mean after I read the link you provide now I see `feof` is depends on `fread`.